# Best approach to allocate dedicated background thread in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I need to create a dedicated thread listening on `DatagramSocket`.
Old school approach would be to create one during context creation:

```
@Bean
void beanDef() {
   var thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
   thread.setDaemon(true);
   thread.start();
}
```

More modern approach would be to create an executor:

```
@Bean
Executor() {
   var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(myRunnable);
}
```

Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would be a modern way to launch a background thread in Spring:

```
@Component
public class MySocketListenerLauncher {

 private ExecutorService executorService;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {

  BasicThreadFactory factory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
    .namingPattern("socket-listener-%d").build();

  executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
  executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    // ... listen to socket ...
   }
  });

  executorService.shutdown();

 }

 @PreDestroy
 public void shutdown() {
  if (executorService != null) {
   executorService.shutdownNow();
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `@Async` annotation to create a thread in the background.
The `@EnableAsync` annotation switches on Spring's ability to run `@Async` methods in a background thread pool. This class also customizes the used Executor.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean(name = "specificTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor specificTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

and in below snippet

```
@Async("specificTaskExecutor")
public void runFromAnotherThreadPool() {
    System.out.println("You function code here");
}
```

I hope this will help you.